# Allow A Header View for Only Certain Sections Using an iOS UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

The code below displays my header view correctly, but for each of the sections in the UICollectionView:

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
          viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionReusableView * headerView =
        [collectionView 
            dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader 
                               withReuseIdentifier:@"SectionHeaderCollectionReusableView"
                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case Section_One:
            return headerView;
        case Section_Two:
            return headerView;
        case Section_Three:
            return headerView;
        case Section_Four:
            return headerView;
        case Section_Five:
            return headerView;

        default:
            return headerView;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do instead, is not display a header view for 'Section_One' or 'Section_Two', but returning 'nil' results in an 'NSInternalInconsistencyException':

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
          viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionReusableView * headerView =
        [collectionView 
            dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader 
                               withReuseIdentifier:@"SectionHeaderCollectionReusableView"
                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case Section_One:
            return nil;
        case Section_Two:
            return nil;
        case Section_Three:
            return headerView;
        case Section_Four:
            return headerView;
        case Section_Five:
            return headerView;

        default:
            return nil;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to display a header view for only certain sections?

Comment: What other details are offered with the `NSInternalInconsistencyException`?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil ((null))'

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Go ahead and return a header for each section and then set the size of the section header to have a size of zero in this UICollectionViewDelegate function.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return CGSizeZero;
    }else {
        return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, desiredHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the same controller handles two collection views and you want no headers and sections in the other collection view? It seems like a bad practice to just return "some" header for both of the views?

Comment: (I added an answer below regarding this.)

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro That's a specific use case and should likely be handled in a separate question.

Comment: Why, Apple, why?

Comment: Three-years-old comment... note that you can get the reference size if your layout is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, that way you can delegate the "desired size" to the Storyboard and making your code more "MVC"-compatible: `return [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout headerReferenceSize];`

Answer (score 8):

I had a case with one `UICollectionViewController` controlling two `UICollectionView`s (referenced later as collection view 1 and 2) and I wanted headers to the first and no headers (or footers) to the second.

What's missing from @mwright's answer is that when you return `CGSizeZero` for **collection view 2** as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == self.collectionView2 {
        return CGSizeZero
    }
    return < something else >
}
```

... means that the `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` **does not** get called at all for **collection view 2**.

Meaning that you don't need to worry about returning a "wrong" header for the second collection view in vain.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that the ***accepted answer broke*** when you used AutoLayout in the XIB for the reusable header.

It was especially broken if you spaced the content from the edges or gave the items inside the header view a static, immutable size. Setting the header size to CGSizeZero cluttered my debugger console with dozens of warnings from Interface Builder saying that they'd break all the constraints to meet the requirement set in the delegate method.

While that in itself is not *technically* a disaster, it's still dirty. And in the age of Swift and AutoLayout there has to be a cleaner solution. Also you never want to ship that sort of thing to a client when you're at work.

To fix this, instead of just invoking `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` and returning `CGSizeZero` I created another subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` with XIB and set the height of the view inside it to `0`.

Then later, I dequeue that variant outside my `switch` statement contained within the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method. This satisfies both Interface Builder *and* visual requirements!

Beats having hundreds of unsatisfiable constraint warnings printed in the Console while you're debugging, anyhow.

Comment: this is for a specific case where you are providing a header view other than the default and would likely be better handled in a separate question

Comment: Actually @mwright this is a helpful answer and it should stay on this question. Thanks cocotutch

Comment: You misunderstand, I didn't say it wasn't helpful, I said it wasn't directly pertinent to the question that was asked. The asker did not specify that they were using a custom header with autolayout, in which case this would be correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

### If you return a value of size (0, 0), no header will be added.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

 switch section {
 case 0:
   return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 70)
 case 1:
   return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) // NO HEADER WILL BE ADDED
 case 2:
   return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 70)
 case 3:
   return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) // NO HEADER WILL BE ADDED
 default:
   return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 70)
 }

}
```

Answer (score -7):

Try returning an empty view. Probably a better way but this could work....

Comment: "return [UICollectionReusableView new];" results in the same exception unfortunately.  Is there a different way to return an empty view?

Comment: UIView *eView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];

Comment: You will have to make it a property in order to use it in your collection view delegate/datasource

Comment: Instantiating the view in this way as a local variable within the 'viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind' results in the same exception. Adding a property and assigning it also throws the exception (whether instantiated within the method or in viewDidLoad).